# get data from multiple react child and send into one API

Tags: reactjs, api

I have 4 react component, called A, B, C and D. A is the parent component, B, C and D is the child component that placed in component A. Each component would produce data (user input), but the submit button/action placed in the parent component (component A). Then, all the data from all component will be sent into one API, called http://localhost:8000/create_data. I make it sent into one API because I want to process all the data first then input in into my database.

1st approach:
the submit button is an onClick event which doing setState in componentA

```
state = {
    instruction: 'not submit'
}

instruction = () => {
    this.setState({
        instruction: 'submit'
    })
}

<componentB instruction={this.state.instruction}/>
<componentC instruction={this.state.instruction}/>
<componentD instruction={this.state.instruction}/>
<Button type="button" color="primary" onClick={this.instruction}>Submit</Button>
```

then, in each child component, I create componentWillReceiveProps(), looks like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps = (val) => {
    const messages = 'this is from componentB';
    if (val.instruction === 'submit') {
        axios.post('http://localhost:8000/create_data', {
            value: messages
        })
    }
}
```

in server,

```
app.post('/create_data', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.value)
    // this single console log print three value:
    // this is from componentB
    // this is from componentC
    // this is from componentD
    // I dont know how to separate them
})
```

2nd approach:
I tried to pass one more props to each child, which is a function. So, when the this.state.instruction change into 'submit', I call the props function and passed the value from the child to the parent. I got the value, but then, how I suppose to send it into the one API since I pass three different function as props to each component.

any other better way to achive it? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it all wrong, below is a better way to implement what your trying to achieve;

```
class A extends Component {

   state = {
       messages: {
          b:'',
          c:'',
          d: ''
        }
     }

    handleSubmit = () => {
        const { messages } = this.state
        // you could check if messages is not empty before sending
        axios.post('http://localhost:8000/create_data', {
        value: messages
       })
     }

    handleMessageChange = (name, message) => {
       // perform validations on message before adding it to state
       const {messages} = this.state
       this.setState({messages: {...messages, [name]:message}})
     }

  render(){
    const {messages} = this.state
    const b='b'
    const c='c'
    const d='d'
    return(
       <div>
        <componentB 
          message={message[b]} 
          name={b} 
          onChange={this.handleMessageChange}
         />
        <componentC 
          message={message[c]} 
          name={c} 
          onChange={this.handleMessageChange}
         />
        <componentD 
          message={message[d]} 
          name={d} 
          onChange={this.handleMessageChange}
         />

         <Button 
           type="button" 
           color="primary" 
           onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
           Submit
         </Button>
       </div>
       )
      }
```

And your components B, C, and D should look like this below;

```
      class ComponentD extends {

         handleChange = (event) => {

             const {name, value} = event.target
             this.props.onChange(name, value)
           }

          render() {
            const {message, name} = this.props
            return(
               <input 
                 name={name} 
                 value={message} 
                 onChange={this.handleChange}
               />
            )
           }
         }
```

If a child component has multiple inputs, you could do the following

`Child component EF`

```
      class ComponentEF extends {

     handleChange = (event) => {

         const {name, value} = event.target
         this.props.onChange(name, value)
       }

      render() {
        const {messages:{e,f}} = this.props
        return(
          <React.Fragment>
           <input 
             name="e" 
             value={e} 
             onChange={this.handleChange}
           />
           <input 
             name="f" 
             value={f} 
             onChange={this.handleChange}
           />
         </React.Fragment>
        )
       }
     }
```

`In the parent component`

```
  render(){
     const {messages:{b,c,d,...rest}} = this.state
    return(
        <div>
          <componentB 
            message={b} 
            name={"b"} 
            onChange={this.handleMessageChange}
          />
         <componentC 
            message={c} 
            name={"c"} 
            onChange={this.handleMessageChange}
         />
         <componentD 
            message={d} 
            name={"d"} 
            onChange={this.handleMessageChange}
         />
          <componentEF
            messages={rest} 
            onChange={this.handleMessageChange}
         />

         <Button 
           type="button" 
           color="primary" 
           onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
            Submit
         </Button>
   </div>
   )
  }
```

Comment: Dear Rex, seems like this line has a typeError: this.setState({messages: {...messages.[name]:message}}), what is it suppose to?

Comment: It supposes to update message when there is a change. I have fixed the reason you are getting that error. Check above for the update

Comment: I'll try it first

Comment: Dear Rex, I almost get it. What if in the child component has a multiple input?

Comment: Dear Rex, could you please help me, what if the child has more than one input? How the parent could access all the data. Thank you in advance for helping me.

Comment: Akza, I have updated the answer above. If you have any more question don't hesitate to ask

Comment: Hang on, i'll try it first :DDD

Comment: Dear Rex, the result is just an empty string. Did u know why? ._.

Comment: Nope, sorry I don't.  Hope you know that we have gone beyond the scope of your initial question?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is an issue with binding. Try `<Button type="button" color="primary" onClick={this.instruction.bind(this)}>Submit</Button>`

Comment: not working. I mean, I still get the same result. No error, but I did not know how to separate the value in the server (first approach), and did not know how to send the value to the server (second approach)

Comment: ok, a couple of things: 

(1) if you want to process the data before sending it to your server, you don't need to hit an API. Just process the data in your parent component. 

(2) React Components need to start with capital letters. 

(3) You do not need to use componentWillReceiveProps in child components *unless* you want to control whether and when the child components re-render. They will do so automatically when you call a bound method in a parent component. 

here's a working gist of what I think you're describing: https://gist.github.com/sehailey/a5badc17c39e5b523fa00aceff03a7b6

Comment: console.log("Do some processing here? And then maybe some POST method"); what I could do if the instruction to submit (to collect the data first by change the this.state.instruction) is fired after the process?